# What Happens If A Router Added To The Wrong Area Instead Of The Area 0?

Tags: networking, ospf, loop

Considering This Topology:

[image]

Which is a part of the Practical Networking youtube educational channel, we can see three areas.

The teacher said that all traffic should go through Area 0 to keep a Hub and Spoke design, and to avoid routing loops.

My questions:

1- Isn't OSPF a loop-free protocol? Shouldn't it avoid loops automatically?
2- What happens if we add new router R8 to:

1. Area 88 and Area 99?
2. Area 88, Area 99, and Area 0?

I tried to find an answer on the Internet, but it is always around the subject and not to the point answer. I also tried to create a Packet Tracer lab to simulate the topology but I couldn't find a 4-port router to simulate the R03 router.

As I am a novice, I will appreciate simplified answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1- Isn't OSPF a loop-free protocol? Shouldn't it avoid loops automatically?

OSPF is loop-free precisely because all inter-area traffic must go through area 0

> 2- What happens if we add new router R8 to:
>
> Area 88 and Area 99?

The router will not advertise area 99 routes into 88, and vice versa.  Note that any device using this router as a gateway *will* be able to reach the other area, as the router has routes for both.

> Area 88, Area 99, and Area 0?

The router becomes another ABR for 88 and 99, but again does not advertise 88 into 99 (and vice versa).

Answer (score 3):

> 1- Isn't OSPF a loop-free protocol? Shouldn't it avoid loops
> automatically?

Yes, and it will, if you follow it's design rules. Violating the rules might make it hard/impossible to detect a loop. At the Area Border between 0 and non-0 areas, summarization can occur, and summarization must be done with care to prevent loops.

> 2. What happens if we add new router R8 to:
>
>    1. Area 88 and Area 99?

That would be a wrong setup. Any Area Border Router (ABR) must be connected to Area 0 with at least one interface. I might participate in routing in either/both areas, but it will not announce prefixes from one area to the other. Therefore, other intra -area routers in 88 (resp 99) will not forward packets for area 99 (resp. 88) toward R8.

> 2. What happens if we add new router R8 to:
> 3. Area 88, Area 99, and Area 0?

That would be valid, and R8  would be just another regular ABR.